# Maintaining code compatibility between OpenCV 2 and OpenCV 3

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

My library currently uses OpenCV 2. Now, I am trying to compile the library to use OpenCV 3. It seems that some header files were moved and some constants were renamed. For example, `CV_INTER_LINEAR` is not defined in OpenCV 3.

As my library needs to be compiled and run on both OpenCV 2 and 3, Is there any simple way to overcome this incompatibility?
I can change my code, but then it doesn't work in OpenCV 2.

Comment: Hi, have you checked `./modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem a few months ago, and I have to contraddict Kiran: I got my relatively big project to build both with OpenCv 2 and 3. Being able to build with both 2 and 3 is very important in a project transition phase, especially because OpenCV 3 is not in stable version yet, and yet has amazing optimization features.

Isn't `cv::INTER_LINEAR` defined both in OpenCV 2 (header `imgproc/imgproc.hpp`) and 3? You'll have to replace some constant names, add a couple of inclusions, but that won't be too hard.

Regarding header inclusions, there's a way to find an including path compatible both for Opencv2 and 3.

From the [link Kiran posted](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog#30-alpha):

> In OpenCV 3 we write
>
> ```
> #include "opencv2/core.hpp"
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
> ```
>
> **The old method should also work.**

**Update**
In the [new Release Candidate](http://opencv.org/downloads.html), [it's reported](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog) they have improved compatibility between OpenCV 2.4 and 3.x

> Improved compatibility with OpenCV 2.4:
>
> - 2.4.11 now includes "opencv2/core.hpp" and other such headers in addition to standard "opencv2/core/core.hpp".
> - smart pointers (Ptr<>)
>     can now be created in both 2.4 and 3.0 style (new ClassName(params) vs
>     makePtr(params))
> - trained and stored stat models from
>     opencv_ml 2.4 can now be loaded and used by opencv_ml 3.0 as-is.
> - the
>     2.4=>3.0 transition guide has been sketched: http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html

Answer (score 5):

EDIT:- Read Antonio's answer. You can include compatibility header `types_c.h`([1](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3.0.0-beta/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h#L346)) and use OpenCV 2 constant names which works in OpenCV 3 also. This is since, even though constant names differ (e.g. `INTER_LINEAR` vs `CV_INTER_LINEAR`),  constant *values* remain the same([2](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4.11/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp#L555)). So functions accepting integer const values  should behave no different in OpenCV 2 and 3. Same is the case for other constants also. This way you just have to change header paths between OpenCV 2 and 3.

OLD ANSWER:- This is not possible. OpenCV 3 is not completely backward compatible with OpenCV 2. You will have to change enums, header paths etc between OpenCV 2 and 3. See Changelog([3](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog)) for sections about backward compatibility.

You could try things like copying headers around, giving numbers instead of constant names, using `#ifdefs` all over your code - *but sooner or later that is going to fail*. I suggest maintaining separate copies and have peace of mind. I would rather ignore OpenCV 2 altogether unless I am currently in production.

Comment: Thanks, but that is bad from opencv developers. They should have a way to maintain code written for V2 and make them compatible with V3.

Comment: @mans If every library developer thought so, we all will still be using OpenGL 1.  More of a spec, still.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenCV guys have put up a transition guide online : http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html

In essence I think the following have changed:-

- ml module-> The existence of StatModel in OpenCV 3 and that being the root for all classifiers.
- features2d and xfeatures2d -> SIFT and a couple of others have moved from being in the core repository to the opencv_contrib repo
- And many others I am not aware of

As for code working with Opencv3 and opencv2, I usually introduce a prepocessor directive which holds a flag:-

```
#define HAS_OPENCV3 1
#ifdef HAS_OPENCV3
#include <opencv2/core.hpp> //Any OPENCV3 code
#else
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp> //Any Opencv2 code
#endif
```

Since the relative portions are eliminated before compilation, it will also compile with only the OpenCV2 or OpenCV3 libraries. But, introduces a lot of redundancy (which can be avoided by some clever coding).