# Is there a cheatsheet for OpenCV 3? what are key differences in v3?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

Is there a **cheatsheet** for **OpenCV 3**? what are additional features and functions in OpenCV3 that need to be considered?

Also, most important - what are the functions and modules that are no more available in OpenCV 3?

Note : I notice that there is a cheat sheet for 2.4. Is that still good for OpenCV 3 also?

Comment: I don't know of a cheat sheet for 3.0, but you can get information about compatibility [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750616/maintaining-code-compatibility-between-opencv-2-and-opencv-3), specifically http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html#gsc.tab=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In "Learning OpenCV 3" by Adrian Kaehler & Gary Bradsky (the library founder), the second release (2017-01-20), there's link to Cheat Sheet:

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/opencv_cheatsheet.pdf

..but it points to "OpenCV 2.4 Cheat Sheet (C++)". So I assume there's no official OpenCV 3.x Cheat Sheet.

For changes in the library introduced to 3.0 you can refer to this page:

http://opencv.org/opencv-3-0.html

Answer (score 3):

There is one for Python and OpenCV 4 here:
[OpenCV 4 + Python cheat sheet](https://github.com/a-anjos/python-opencv/blob/master/cv2cheatsheet.pdf)